# How to identify all records in MC that are not in a Synchronized Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, contact-deletion

I recently synched over a large number of Salesforce Leads for an email campaign. I now want to remove those Leads from MC.

My first step was to adjust the sync settings in Contact Builder, which is now up to date.

I then tried this SQL, but it's not populating my Data Extension with any records. I think the SQL needs some tweaking, but I'm not sure what it should be. Basically, I'm trying to say: show me everyone who is a record or Subscriber in MC but is not in the Lead_Salesforce synchronized data extension.

```
SELECT  
sub.EmailAddress as Email,
t1.Id
FROM  _subscribers as sub 
LEFT JOIN
        Lead_Salesforce t1
ON      t1.Id = sub.SubscriberKey
WHERE   t1.Id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT  
EmailAddress as Email,
SubscriberKey as Id
FROM  _subscribers 
WHERE   SubscriberKey NOT IN (
  SELECT Id as SubscriberKey FROM Lead_Salesforce
)
```

Comment: this SQL ran but didn't return any results in the DE. The Synced DE for Leads has about 1K records in it and when running the Contact Count report it shows there are about 120K leads synced from SFDC. Could I be doing something wrong with the SQL or am I looking at the issue the wrong way?

Comment: I updated the SQL. The JOIN is probably why you are getting 0 results and I don't think you need it.